# Why was this edit approved?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

The edit https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68075911/2 was [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31809821) by a majority of 2 against 1 rejecting review. None of the reviewers was the post author.

The reject reason, as specified by the rejecting reviewer, was:

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

I agree with that. The previous revision better matched the code in the question and [has the same effect (for this code)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9cd10414fce2c252c3ba4a609dd77bd0). The edit explanation ("allow line was in an incorrect location") is not correct if I understand correctly that it claims the previous revision did not have the desired outcome.

I don't understand why the other reviewers approved it. I'm hesitant to roll it back myself, because maybe they had a reason. Should I?

Comment: It was [just rejected by Ryan M♦ one minute ago](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31809821), so a diamond mod agreed the edit was wrong.

Comment: Just a quick FYI, you don't need to create a meta post for each and every bad review you encounter: we have [BSOR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews) chat room. It is frequented by moderators and active reviewers who can both help get the incorrect outcome overridden.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It should not have been approved.  I've reversed the approval.

---

I don't know Rust, but regardless of whether the edit is *correct*, it definitely completely changes the answer.  The question was about how to use the `allow` directive.  Changing how it's used makes it a different answer.  The editor should have posted it as their own answer, and the reviewers should have rejected it as "Clearly conflicts with author's intent".